# Green lines in GStreamer video

Tags: c, video, gstreamer

[image]I am using Gstreamer 1.0 for video playback, and have a custom area set for showing the video by `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle`.

The problem is, in some videos green lines at the sides of the video area are shown that somehow are transparent yet quite distracting because of their color.

Do you know what caused them or how I can get rid of them?

Would appreciate any help :)

regards, tagelicht

Comment: btw, I am using a `playbin` element for video playback

Answer (score 1):

I think this bug was reported at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732351, still unsolved though. I'd recommend you interact there at the bug to get it in motion.